# Obtaining Role by User id with Restull API

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm trying to obtain the role of some user (by its id), currently i do this way:

*$this is a home-made API access outside of SugarCRM, the session is implicitly sent*

```
$roles = $this->get_entry_list('ACLRoles', null, null, null, array('name'));
       if ($roles) {
            foreach ($roles->entry_list as $role) {
                $result = $this->get_relationships('ACLRoles', $role->id, 'users', 'user_id=' . $userId);
                if (count($result->entry_list) > 0) {
                    return array(
                        'id' => $role->id,
                        'name' => $role->name_value_list->name->value
                    );
                }
            }
       }
```

I, however, consider this an inefficient solution, due that i need to iterate over all the roles to check if the user is there... I have been looking at the API and been trying other methods, but i cannot get to relation Users -> ACLRoles, only ACLRoles -> Users...

Is there a better way to get the Role of an User?

Comment: I think that's the best choice unfortunately...

Comment: I though so, but i was hoping that someone else would point me to something else, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to add a new web services call via your own custom endpoint. This is actually quite simple to do, see this KB article for more details...

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.6/02_Application_Framework/Web_Services/06_Extending_Web_Services

Answer (score 0):

I'm using get_relationships in Sugar 6.5.8 to retrieve the roles for a given user via the SOAP service.

```
get_relationships(sessionId, "Users", userId, "aclroles", "", array("id", "name"))
```

Note: the link_field_name (4th) parameter appears to be case-sensitive, but doesn't error if you get it wrong like the module_name parameter... it is just ignored and no records returned.